# Cannot resole symbol in android sdk source code

Tags: android, debugging, sdk

I'm a newer to android develop. I debugged my android app on AndroidStudio today and I got Logcat below:

```
09-04 11:39:46.730    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell I/dalvikvm: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class Lcom/flurry/android/d; v=0x0
09-04 11:39:46.730    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/flurry/android/d
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at com.flurry.android.s.q(SourceFile:1772)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at com.flurry.android.s.p(SourceFile:1726)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at com.flurry.android.s.b(SourceFile:1715)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at com.flurry.android.dd.a(SourceFile:1706)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at com.flurry.android.bw.run(SourceFile:45)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell W/System.err: at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-04 11:39:46.773    1859-1878/com.tsf.shell E/FlurryAgent: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/flurry/android/d
        at com.flurry.android.s.q(SourceFile:1772)
        at com.flurry.android.s.p(SourceFile:1726)
        at com.flurry.android.s.b(SourceFile:1715)
        at com.flurry.android.dd.a(SourceFile:1706)
        at com.flurry.android.bw.run(SourceFile:45)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

It shows "NoClassDefFoundError". So I kept track with it and try to figure it out. But I got many **"cannot resolve symbol xxx"** problem shows in **Android SDK source** code during my tracking, and found all of it are cause by wrong quoted. How it happen? In source code and numbers. I thought it might be the problem. Should I fix it myself? Or Was I wrong or miss something in some step? Thanks if you have any idea about it.

**Edit:** To make it clearer, I add an doodle picture for it.(PS:I didn't know whether it was the cause to the error. Or I just **ignore** it?)
[image]

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You aren't including the Flurry library in your install (either as a library package or built into your `apk`). You need to set it as a dependency from your app.

Comment: @micro.pravi :It might not my code's problem. I add an picture to make it clearer.

Comment: @chrylis: You got the point. But I have no implement use in "Flurry library" on my project. I finally found it did not show on my emulator. Even it was my phone's another app's problem, why it show during I debugged my app. And do you know the "sdk source" problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:
1. Clean/Rebuild Project
2. Invalidate Caches/Restart